Flutter project running issue on Flutter 3.19.5 on Android: Deletion of android folder necessary?
When I tried to run my Flutter project, I keep on getting the same error. It appears to have started to appear after upgrading to Flutter 3.16 according to:
[https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply]
As per my research, the imperative apply of Flutter's Gradle plugins has been deprecated. I don't know much about it, as I am not a Flutter or Android dev expert.
Some solutions I discovered involve deleting the android folder and recreating it with versions after 3.16. I am currently using Flutter 3.19.5, which is the recommended version for this project.
What confuses me is that when I first cloned the project, the android folder was already present, and other developers using the same Flutter version are not experiencing this problem. So, why am I the only one who needs to delete the Android folder? It's worth noting that other developers are using the android folder without issue on the most recent Flutter versions.
I'm hesitant to delete the android folder because it may contain custom configurations vital to the project.
Also, I've attached a snapshot of the issue for reference.
Any insights or guidance on how to resolve this discrepancy would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I've tried deleting the android folder also, that creates more issues with some dependencies and stuff. The project doesn't run that way too.
